# Usefulness of hierarchical variables in ML model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic, classification, categorical-data

I am working on a binary classification problem with 1000 rows and 20 variables.

The problem is about finding which product will meet the expected order quantities. We already have examples of certain products meeting expected order quantities and certain products not meeting the expected quantities. So, we have labels of positive and negative cases. Now, if a new order (for a specific product) comes in, we would like to know what is the likelihood that it will meet the expected order quantity (positive class) and if yes, what are the factors/variables which are influencing the outcome. I intend to use logistic regression for this problem

My objective is to find out which product, from which region

I have variables like `product_id`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `product family`, `product type`, `product segment` etc etc..

As you can see that most of my variables are hierarchical variables. Meaning, if I know the city name, I can infer/populate other variables like `state`, `country` etc.

Same with `product_id` as well. If I know `product_id` info, I can get all info about `product_family`, `product_segment`, `product type` etc.

My questions are as follows

a) So, should I use only the granular level detail variables in my ML model and ignore other levels of same variable? because I guess it would be correlated

b) Any suggestion or tips on how can we handle this scenario in our model?

c) Should I drop this project because I only have very few granular level detail variables (and rest of it can be inferred based on them even without using AI)?

d) If I make a prediction, I believe the contribution of hierarchical variable is same. For ex: If variable `city` contributes to prediction by 10%, am I right that `state`, `country` all contribute the same 10% as well. (meaning all together contribute 10% to the outcome)

Can you help me with this please? Looking forward to your inputs

Answer (score 1):

> should I use only the granular level detail variables in my ML model and ignore other levels of same variable? because I guess it would be correlated

It depends on how much variation there is within the heirarchies.  I'm not really sure what the difference is between product family and product segment is so let me give you a different example.

Cars have this same sort of structure.  Within brands there are different models, within models there are different trim levels.  There is a lot of variation within trim levels that can be explained by model, and so forth.  So just using the most granular level leaves a lot of information out, and if there are few examples of a particular trim it can be difficult to estimate its sales price (for example).

> b) Any suggestion or tips on how can we handle this scenario in our model?

Aside from general advice, we would need to know what the goal of your analysis is.

> c)Should I drop this project because I only have very few granular level detail variables (and rest of it can be inferred based on them even without using AI)?

See my second point

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help and also updated the post with background info about project. Hope this helps